# How to login to facebook using cookies in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, puppeteer, setcookie

Is this the correct way of using cookies to login in facebook using puppeteer?

```
const run = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/login");
  await page.type("#email", process.env.EMAIL);
  await page.type("#pass", process.env.PASSWORD);

  await page.click("#loginbutton");

  const toSaveCookies = await page.cookies();
  await fs.writeFile("./cookies.json", JSON.stringify(toSaveCookies, null, 2));
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.screenshot({ path: "after-login.jpg" });

  const cookies = require("../cookies.json");
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page2 = await context.newPage();

  await page2.setCookie(...cookies);

  await page2.goto("https://www.facebook.com/login", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });
  await page2.screenshot({ path: "login-using-cookies.jpg" });
  await browser.close();
};

run();
```

I tried to set cookie manually with:

```
await page.setCookies(cookie[0],cookie[1],cookie[2],cookie[3])
```

but it didn't work and i also tried:

```
for (let cookie of cookies) {
     await page.setCookie(cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You stringify the cookies when saving, so you need to parse them when reading.

Here is the code we use to conditionally login on a different website. When navigating to a page that requires an authentication, the user is redirected to the login page unless the cookies are valid:

```
        try {
            const cookiesString = await readFile(conf.cookiesFile);
            console.log('==> ' + scriptName + ' cookies: ' + cookiesString);
            if(cookiesString) {
                const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
                await page.setCookie(...cookies);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('==> ' + scriptName + ' read cookies error: ' + err);
        }
        console.log('==> ' + scriptName + ': load ' + conf.admin.url);
        await page.goto(conf.admin.url, { waitUntil: 'load' });
        if(page.url().match(/\/login\//)) {
            // need to login
            console.log('==> ' + scriptName + ': login as ' + conf.login.username + ' at ' + page.url());
            await page.type('#loginusername', conf.login.username, { delay: 500 });
            await page.type('#password',      conf.login.password, { delay: 500 });
            await Promise.all([
                await page.click('#signin'),
                await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
            ]);
            const cookies = await page.cookies();
            try {
                await writeFile(conf.cookiesFile, JSON.stringify(cookies));
            } catch(err) {
                console.log('==> ' + scriptName + ' write cookies error: ' + err);
            }
        }
```